# Making 3D background blend in with video

Tags: modeling, video

So I'm building a 3D set that I can green screen in since I can't afford to build or rent a pro studio. So I'm having some trouble with making it look real  with video footage, or as close to real as I can make it. Between the blender camera and the real camera I've matched the distance between camera and subject,  the focal length and the height, I've also added DOF, the camera sensor is 1/2.84", the crop factor is 7.3024, but I think these are small potatoes in comparison to the lighting and materials.

So what I'm looking for is some advice on what to do next, or what I should work on. I've combed through the stack exchange for various different problems and I've got a lot from it and at this point I need to know where to go. I'm thinking lighting is the problem, in blender and in real life. In blender I'm going to put a human mesh and see how to the light looks in blender and replicate that in real life with the lights I have.

Some other thoughts I have, I think some things are too small, including the screen in the back (look at the window panes in reference image) but again I think the biggest problem is the lighting. How I built the walls is I modeled the window panes added materials as needed and have an emission panel for each window pane. As you see below I have reference images to what I'm building, I don't want the same camera angle as it won't fit my space for recording in real life and below you can see the raw render out of blender then added some saturation. It looks a lot better but it still looks fake.

Yes I know there's a hole or cut out in the floor on the reference image, I'm thinking of adding it in my render, let me know if you think it should be in there. Also don't worry about the black muddiness under the chairs, that's the green screen keying I'll worry about that later.

In short, I want to get opinions on what I should work on. I think it's lighting at this point, but tell me what you think is not selling this render.

[image]
[image]